# Jmeter function ${__time(,)} value not getting updated

Tags: jmeter

1. I have an http heartbeat request in a while(SendHeartbeat is 1) controller
2. Along with the request there is a postprocessor with code as mentioned below
3. Here AgentDuration is 60000(1 min) and LoginTime is set to time when login http request is fired
4. Here I should be out of while loop after 1 minute of agent login
5. However that is never happening because if condition is always evaluating to false because value of `${__time(,)}`  is always being set to the value of time when the postprocessor was first run in the while loop.

Code:

```
 if(${__time(,)} - vars.get("LoginTime").toLong() >
vars.get("AgentDuration").toLong())
 {
        vars.put("SendHeartbeat", "0")
        log.info("C1 disconnected at: " + ${__time(,)}.toString())
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `${}` syntax inside scripts, use `getTime()` instead of `${__time(,)}`:

```
 if(new Date().getTime() - vars.get("LoginTime").toLong() > vars.get("AgentDuration").toLong()) {
```